# Can (the partial sums of) a conditionally convergent series always be written as an alternating sequence of decreasing terms?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

> True or false:
>
> If $\ \sum a_n\ $ is conditionally convergent series, then there exists
> an increasing sequence of  integers $\ k_1,\ k_2,\ k_3,\ldots\ $ such
> that
>
> $$\ \left(\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{k_1} a_n\ ,\ \sum_{n=k_1+1}^{k_2}
> a_n\ ,\ \sum_{n=k_2+1}^{k_3} a_n\ ,\ \ldots\right)\ $$
>
> is an alternating sequence of decreasing terms.

Obviously, a [conditionally convergent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence) must have an infinite amount of positive terms and an infinite amount of negative terms.

Edit: I think for any conditionally convergent, such a sequence of partial sums (split like above) should exist:

1. One where there is a sequence of only negative terms whose absolute value are decreasing, or;
2. One where there is a sequence of only positive terms whose absolute value are decreasing, or;
3. An alternating sequence of decreasing terms (as in the original question).

But I am not sure even of this. But this is the line of thinking I am going down.

Also, this question and it's sentiments are probably closely related to the Riemann Series Theorem, whose proof I admittedly do not know the details to.

**If** the answer is yes, then this would help me answer some other, more specific questions I have on conditionally convergent series (because it would be a useful way to re-write the series without rearranging the terms.)

Further edit: [Vaguely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207651/for-any-real-sequence-can-we-make-it-so-that-if-we-sum-parts-of-its-series?noredirect=1#comment8733379_4207651)

Comment: Do you mean to break $a_n$ into a finite sequence of individually convergent infinite sequences, an in infinite sequence of finite sequences, or some other combination of infinitely/finitely many infinite/finite convergent/divergent sequences?

Comment: @ R. Burton - I don't intend to be rude or blunt, but my question seems to me to be more explicit and unambiguous than your clarification question. Either that, or I don't understand your clarification question.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you can rearrange the terms of $a_n$ in any number of ways. Part of what makes a conditionally convergent sequence conditionally convergent is being able to rearrange the terms to get different results. If there is any arrangement of subsequences whose sums converge, then there are arbitrarily many such arrangement of arbitrary lengths.

Comment: But my rearrangement conditions are very specific. The Reimann Series Theorem requires for you to consider the original series into many subseries of infinite length, and you can the result can be any number you desire. My requirements do not permit such rearrangements.

Answer (score 1):

> True or false:
>
> If $\ \sum a_n\ $ is conditionally convergent series, then there exists
> an increasing sequence of  integers $\ k_1,\ k_2,\ k_3,\ldots\ $ such
> that
>
> $$\left(\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{k_1} a_n\ ,\ \sum_{n=k_1+1}^{k_2}
> a_n\ ,\ \sum_{n=k_2+1}^{k_3} a_n\ ,\ \ldots\right)$$
>
> is an alternating sequence of decreasing terms.

True.

Partition the positive integers as follows:

Let $a_1\in K_1$, then, for any $m,n\in\Bbb Z^+$:

If $a_n\in K_m$ and $a_n\cdot a_{n+1}\ge0$, then $a_{n+1}\in K_m$.

If $a_n\in K_m$ and $a_n\cdot a_{n+1}<0$ then $a_{n+1}\in K_{m+1}$.

It follows that if $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in K_m}a_n$ is positive, then $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in K_{m+1}}a_n$ is negative, and vice-versa. That the sequence...

$$A_m=\sum_{n\in K_m} a_n$$

...decreases (in absolute value, which is what I assume is meant) is guaranteed by the fact $A_m$ must converge to zero in order that $\sum_m A_m$ be convergent.

We in turn know that $\sum_m A_m$ is converges, because it is exactly equal $\sum_n a_n$.

Finally, $k_m=\max K_m$.