# For *any* real sequence, can we make it so that, if we sum parts of it's series in order the terms came in, the resulting sequence is monotone?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

I was inspired by my own question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207518/can-the-partial-sums-of-a-conditionally-convergent-series-always-be-written-as?noredirect=1#comment8733130_4207518), to ask a far more general one:

> If $\ (a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ is a sequence of real numbers, then
> does there exist a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers $\
> k_1,\ k_2,\ k_3,\ \ldots\ \quad $ i.e. $\ k_1<k_2<k_3<\ldots\ $ such
> that the following sequence,
>
> $$\ \left(\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{k_1} a_n\ ,\ \sum_{n=k_1+1}^{k_2}
> a_n\ ,\ \sum_{n=k_2+1}^{k_3} a_n\ ,\ \ldots\right)\ $$
>
> is a **monotone** sequence of real numbers.

By monotone, I mean the sequence is either non-increasing or non-decreasing.

I can't think of a counter-example off the top of my head. However, I have no idea how I would go about proving such a result. I think that this would be quite an amazing result if true.

I am thinking that such a counter-example *similar to* $\ (a_n) = (\ 1,\ 0,\ -1,\ 0,\ 1,\ 0,\ -1,\ 0,\ \ldots)\ $ should exist (i.e. there's no way to split this up in the above requirement in order to make this monotone). Clearly this isn't true for this sequence: $(1+0+-1,\ 0+1+0+-1,\ 0+1+0+-1,\ 0+1+0+-1,\ \ldots) = (0,\ 0,\ 0,\ \ldots)\ $ is monotone. But like I say, I feel like there ought to be an oscillating counter-example related to this one.

If the answer is yes, then I guess we would have to do some sort of proof by contradiction [direct proof seems harder]. "Suppose such a counter-example exists. But such a counter-example cannot exist, because if it did, we get some sort of contradiction."

Comment: @StevenStadnicki That was my initial thought as well, but notice that the OP's sequence of sums is *not* actually a subsequence of the sequence of partial sums - each term is a *difference* of partial sums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:** Consider the sequence

$$
a_n = \begin{cases}
-1 && \text{if } n=1 \\
\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} && \text{if } n>1
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Yeah, didn't think of that. Nice one.

Comment: for people stupid like me: first sum would be negative - others positive and decreasing, thus sequence increases once and decreases all other times, thus non-monotonic